# Trying to fit long word in to span

Tags: html, css

Hello sorry for my bad english

I looking for answer on internet but it couldn't help me somehow maybe i just cant figure it out. I just need to fit those long word in button.
 [this is how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juXg3.png). I posted my code on jsfiddle below

---

[Jsfiddle FIXED](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/muz7q9xy/3/)

```css
.chkbox {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #FFBB40;
 font: bold;
 width:150px;
 padding: 8px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: none;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 8px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.chkbox span {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.chkbox span:after {
 content: '\2713';
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: -20px;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.chkbox:hover span {
 padding-right: 25px;
}
.chkbox:hover span:after {
 opacity: 1;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="chkbox" id="q1a" name="q1" type="button" value="<?php echo $array['0']['2']; ?>"><label for="q1a"><span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span></label></button>
```

Hello its me i found my problem because there was white-space:nowrap in parent div so i cant fit any word in child elements

```
<div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-animate-opacity" id="divclick3" style="white-space:nowrap;">
buttons with spans 
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE FIXED V.2](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/sxb5ux4L/2/)

there is my broken js and i want to achieve all those 4 buttons in 1 line like this next to it

Comment: You didn't post your code here, you haven't explained what your code is actually doing, you did not explain what exactly you wrote to achieve this and what didn't work about it. And your fiddle link is broken.

Comment: use width: auto. Or look into css ellipsis.

Comment: +Munkhdelger Tumenbayar just remove the css property width

Comment: @csm_dev fixed everything guess. Posted on Codesnip,Jsfiddle link fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
word-break: break-all;
```

to the .chkbox class.

```css
.chkbox {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #FFBB40;
 font: bold;
 width:150px;
 padding: 8px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: none;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 8px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.chkbox span {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.chkbox span:after {
 content: '\2713';
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: -20px;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.chkbox:hover span {
 padding-right: 25px;
}
.chkbox:hover span:after {
 opacity: 1;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="chkbox" id="q1a" name="q1" type="button" value="<?php echo $array['0']['2']; ?>"><label for="q1a"><span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span></label></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be `width:auto;` instead of `width:150px;` inside `.chkbox`

```css
.chkbox {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #FFBB40;
 font: bold;
 width:auto;
 padding: 8px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: none;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 8px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.chkbox span {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.chkbox span:after {
 content: '\2713';
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: -20px;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.chkbox:hover span {
 padding-right: 25px;
}
.chkbox:hover span:after {
 opacity: 1;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="chkbox" id="q1a" name="q1" type="button" value="<?php echo $array['0']['2']; ?>"><label for="q1a"><span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span></label></button>
```

Comment: thank you but i need to fit word to 150px but thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add more content with 150px width then you can enter valuable text instead of garbage value.

```css
.chkbox {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #FFBB40;
 font: bold;
 width:150px;
 padding: 8px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: none;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 8px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.chkbox span {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.chkbox span:after {
 content: '\2713';
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: -20px;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.chkbox:hover span {
 padding-right: 25px;
}
.chkbox:hover span:after {
 opacity: 1;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="chkbox" id="q1a" name="q1" type="button" value="<?php echo $array['0']['2']; ?>"><label for="q1a"><span>this is testing here this is testing here</span></label></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to use `.chkbox span {word-break: break-word}` - [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

You may be able to improve this with hyphenation as well.

I used this [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)

```css
.chkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FFBB40;
  font: bold;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chkbox span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.chkbox span:after {
  content: '\2713';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.chkbox:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.chkbox:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="chkbox" id="q1a" name="q1" type="button" value="<?php echo $array['0']['2']; ?>"><label for="q1a"><span>Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</span></label></button>
```